# How to reach extended class' function?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, object

I have an Vehicle class. From Vehicle, I extend Car class (and some others like Bus, Bike..). Now in my application, I don't know  what kind of vehicle the user will want to work with. So I create a Vehicle object and later asign it the proper object (Car, Bus, ...). After that I want to call some Car's function - but I can't reach it. Why?

```
Vehicle vehicle=null;
. . .
vehicle=new Car();
vehicle.someMethodFromCar(); //can't reach it
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have to cast:

```
((Car) vehicle).someMethodFromCar(); //we can reach it
```

`vehicle` is still declared as a `Vehicle` type. That doesn't change if you assign a subtype of `Vehicle`. And the `Vehicle` class does not have the extra methods from the `Car` class. Casting is the way to call methods from subtypes.

Comment: Is there no other way to do this without casting? Using abstraction or calling superclass ?

Comment: It was my understanding, that `someMethodFromCar` is a method that is only defined and needed on `Car`. So abstraction won't help, because we don't want declare or implement Car-methods on the Vehicle class (forcing all other subtypes to provide implementations...)

Answer (score 3):

Your reference is define by it's declared type, so in your case, you have a Vehicle reference `vehicle` assigned to a Car object, but java only sees the type of the reference, so you can't access any of the Car's methods.
In order to do that you need either to assign your object to a Car variable, or cast your reference to Car.

Answer (score 1):

In order to reach that method, you must cast `vehicle` to `Car`.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways:

1. make vehicle as abstract class. Define common method as abstract in vehicle class. So, when you extends vehicle then subclasses need to implement abstract methods. So, when you do

   Vehical v = new Car();

   v.someOverrideMethod();
   it will call car's method.
2. override method which you want to access at runtime in your subclass. So, when you do like,

   Vehical v = new Car();

   v.someOverrideMethod();

At runtime, JVM will look whose object is created, and that object's method will be called  at runtime.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Those two mehods might come in handy but in my current case I can't work that way.